# Access Update Query Min Value

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying to run an update query on the lowest value of an 'Rank' field. When I add in other criteria to the query, the query updates 0 records. Here's the query:

```
UPDATE Table_Address SET Table_Address.Priority = True
WHERE (
((Table_Address.Priority)=False) AND 
((Table_Address.Order)=(SELECT MIN(Order) FROM Table_Address)) AND 
((Table_Address.ID)=[Forms]![Form_UpdateAddressInfo]![ID]) AND 
((Table_Address.Status)="Good" Or (Table_Address.Status)="Unknown"));
```

When I run the query without my criteria of: Table_Address.Priority=False and (Table_Address.Status)="Good" Or (Table_Address.Status)="Unknown"), the query will update the lowest 'Order' address. The moment I include the other criteria (ie: I want the lowest ordered address, address statuses = Good or Unknown, and an address status with a 'False' priority) it updates 0 records. I'm not too sure where I'm going wrong with this. Thanks.

Comment: What happens if you try to select records with the criteria that produces the unexpected result? Do you get any records back?

Comment: I'm not too sure what you mean by that question. The big problem I was encountering was trying to run an Update query while selecting the 'lowest' value of the 'Order' field. 
If I run the query without the 'Select MIN' part, I can select the records I want, but without the lowest 'Order.'

So my criteria for this query are:
1. Record with the lowest 'Order'
2. Address Priority was False
3. Address Status = 'Good' or 'Unknown'

Update the selected record's Address Priority to True

Comment: I have a table with addresses ranked from 1-5. These addresses also have Good, Bad, and Unknown statuses. Every time an address goes 'Bad,' I want to select the next ranked address with a status of Good or Unknown and then update that address.

Comment: No records meet the critieria of: Priority = False AND (Status = "Good" OR Status = "Unknown"). A record must meet both parameters to be returned.

Comment: But there are records that meet that criteria of 'Priority = False' AND (Status = Good or Status = Unknown). There are 4 records that match those criteria.

Comment: Provide sample raw data and desired output.

Comment: Are you looking for the lowest order which meets the other conditions or the lowest order and only update where it meets the other conditions? Your code is trying to do the latter, but I suspect you really want the former.

Comment: Yes exactly that

Answer (score 0):

If the guess in my previous comment is correct, this may be what you need:

```
UPDATE Table_Address
SET Table_Address.Priority = True
WHERE
    Table_Address.ID=[Forms]![Form_UpdateAddressInfo]![ID]
    AND Table_Address.Order=(
    SELECT MIN(Order) FROM Table_Address
    WHERE
        Table_Address.Priority)=False
        AND Table_Address.ID=[Forms]![Form_UpdateAddressInfo]![ID]
        AND (Table_Address.Status="Good"
            Or Table_Address.Status="Unknown")
);
```

Comment: I had tried that before, however it will update every person's 5 addresses (so about 60 records) rather than just the one person's 1 address I'd like to update. Thank you though. I appreciate the help.

Comment: But then (if I understand) they must all have the same value for Order, how would you identify the first one (or the one to target)?

Comment: Unless, perhaps you are running it multiple times, but only want it to succeed once?

Comment: 'Order' is the term we're using for 'Ranking.' So for example, I would have 5 addresses ordered 1-5. Address Order 1 would be marked 'Bad,' therefore I wanted this update query to mark Address Order 2 as a 'Priority.' 

I did a sort of ugly workaround: I have a query to make a table where it properly queries the lowest 'ordered' address I need. Then I have an update query update based on the record in that table. Thanks for all your help though

Comment: Though your solution doesn't sound ugly. If you use the query as a sub-query you can do it in one step.